# How to change the background of an image using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I was trying to find how to remove/change the background of a grayscale image in Python using PIL package but I failed. What I have is an RGB image which has a white background and I would like to load it, resize, change the background from white to black and save. So far I can do the beginning:

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('my_picture.jpg').convert('LA')
# im1 = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
```

which gives me a grayscale image of a size I want but now I do not know how to change the background. I have found a [really good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465783/how-to-set-background-color-on-image-to-white-with-opencv-in-python?rq=1) using `cv2` for cropping the image out from a green bg and also [another setting the background directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268374/change-the-background-color-to-black), but I couldn't find it for PIL. Is there such an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert image into RGB and get the data. Then do follow the step.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("test_image.jpg")
img = img.convert("RGB")
datas = img.getdata()
new_image_data = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] in list(range(190, 256)):
        new_image_data.append((255, 204, 100))
    else:
        new_image_data.append(item)       

img.putdata(new_image_data)
img.save("test_image_altered_background.jpg")
img.show()
```

You can get some idea from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-convert-method/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question. What are those two limits? `range(190, 256)` and `(255, 204, 100)`. The first should be what I am replacing, if white, then it should be 0s no? And the second should be by what, right?

Comment: Change all white pixels to yellow

Comment: There could be some shades hence, I set the range from `190-256' so that everything get change perfectly.