# Create transparent background for white png image Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, transparency

I have several png designs that are (at least mostly) white/gray (sometimes with a little bit of other colors), so for example when I run

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open('white_design.png')
```

I don't see the image, since the background is white. I would like to add some light gray to the background, but then that could cause problems if a different design was mostly that shade of gray. How can I make the images "transparent" or at least so the designs are visible?

I've tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969021/how-to-change-the-background-of-an-image-using-pil?noredirect=1&lq=1) but that changes the color of the design, which I don't want.

One such image can be generated by running:

```
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import wand.image

r = requests.get("http://www.codazen.com")
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]

svg_xml_url = urls[1] # white logo design

encoded = svg_xml_url.replace("data:image/svg+xml;base64,","")
decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)

with wand.image.Image(blob=decoded, format="svg") as image:
    png_image = image.make_blob("png")
    
with open("image.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(png_image)
```

and returns this: [image: white image] (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygjDJ.png) if you can't see the image)

Comment: You can add one of your pngs here

Comment: @Epsi95 just added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to subtract from the white pixels to make it grey like

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('your_image.png')
np_img = np.array(img)
v = 50 # the more v, the more black
np_img = np_img - [v,v,v,0] #[R, G, B, alpha]
np_img[np_img<0] = 0 # make the negative values to 0

Image.fromarray(np_img.astype('uint8'))
```

If you want to change the background

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('t2.png')
np_img = np.array(img)

bg = np.ones_like(np_img)
bg[:] = [255,0,0,255] # red
bg[:] = [0,255,0,255] # green
bg[:] = [0,0,255,255] # blue
bg[:] = [125,125,125,255] # gray

bg[np_img>0] = 0

np_img = bg + np_img

Image.fromarray(np_img.astype('uint8'))
```

Comment: Looks like that ends up being pretty similar to the link I shared that changed the color of the image. I think the reason that is happening is because when I convert the image to RGBA, it fills the white in with yellow.

Comment: And I think the putalpha command would be the same as your code, e.g.

img.putalpha(200)

Comment: @MitchellPudil I was unable to run your code. It was throwing an error.Can you attach an exact image here? What do you want? Make the background black or gray without making any color alteration to your actual design?

Comment: I'd be happy enough if we can just get the background black and keep the logo white (like we see in the link). I tried attaching an exact image in the problem, but it got automatically adjusted (the way I'm trying to make it look)

Comment: I got MissingDelegateError: no decode delegate for this image format `SVG' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/361

Comment: Have you checked the background change one? Does it solve your problem?