# How to cut background and smooth edges of a photo after cut

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am currently working on a project that is needed to cut background and after all smooth it's borders

What I have as a input:

Input:

[image: Input]

What I wnat to do :

Cut background:

[image: Cut background]

Smooth edges:

[image: Smooth edges]

The idea of code is that after background cut, edges are not perfect and it would be better if these edges have been smoothed

What I tried:
I saves mask edges

```
img_path = 'able.png'
img_data = cv2.imread(img_path)
img_data = img_data > 128


img_data = np.asarray(img_data[:, :, 0], dtype=np.double)
gx, gy = np.gradient(img_data)


temp_edge = gy * gy + gx * gx


temp_edge



temp_edge[temp_edge != 0.0] = 255.0


temp_edge = np.asarray(temp_edge, dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite('mask_edge.png', temp_edge)
```

After all I get stuck

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465783/how-to-set-background-color-on-image-to-white-with-opencv-in-python/58466505#58466505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach:**

Continuing from where you have stopped, load the *cut background* image.

- Blur the image and store in a different variable
- Convert to grayscale and find contour surrounding the region of interest
- Create a mask and draw the contour with certain thickness
- In a new variable keep the blurred pixel values in the contour while leaving the rest from the *cut background* image, with the help of `where()` function from `Numpy`

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread('cut_background.jpg', 1)

img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7), 0)
```

[image]

```
gray =  cv2.cvtColor(img , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th = cv2.threshold(gray,254,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

mask = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (255,255,255),7)
```

[image]

```
result = np.where(mask==(255, 255, 255), img_blur, img )
```

[image]

You can try varying the kernel size used by the Gaussian filter and the thickness of the contour being drawn.

**Update:**

To save the final image with a transparent background:

```
# apply Gaussian blur to th with same kernel size as before
b1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(th, (7, 7), 0)

# merge with existing result
result_trans = cv2.merge((result[:,:,0],result[:,:,1],result[:,:,2], b1))

# or simply use dstack from Numpy
result_trans = np.dstack((result,b1))

# remember to save this result as PNG file to preserve the transparent/alpha channel
cv2.imwrite(r'lena_processed.png', result_trans)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I cannot replicate this case cause when I try to create countour mask, I got only black photo. And as a addition is it possible to save last photo with trasparent background???

Comment: @denysharshanov Please try adjusting the threshold value in `cv2.threshold`.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Is it possible save that picture with transparent background???

Comment: @denysharshanov please check the update

Answer (score 3):

You need to blur the alpha channel.

Your target picture shows no blur in the color information, only in transparency. Blurring the color data will not replicate this faithfully.

Your segmented image is 4-channel. It contains the transparency mask.

```py
im = cv.imread("image.png", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
(height, width) = im.shape[:2]
color = im[:,:,0:3]
alpha_mask = im[:,:,3]

blurred_alpha = cv.GaussianBlur(alpha_mask, ksize=None, sigmaX=7)
```

[image: blurred]

Then compose:

```py
color_f = np.float32(1/255) * color
factor = np.float32(1/255) * blurred_alpha
factor = factor[..., None] # add a dimension for broadcasting
composite = color_f * factor + 1.0 * (1-factor)
# suitable for imshow
```

Composited onto white background:

[image: composite]

That looks wrong because the color information in the transparent pixels can't be relied upon. It is invalid, black even, so you don't see any actual background shining through:

[image: masked lena color channels]

To fix that, I took the color channels from a complete (non-masked) Lena and downsampled it to fit:

```py
big_lena = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("lena.jpg"))
color = cv.resize(big_lena, (width, height), interpolation=cv.INTER_LANCZOS4)
```

[image: composite but better]

You can adjust how close the blur comes to the edges of the mask by dilating or eroding the mask (before blurring it).

You don't need to compose onto (white) background at all. You can just take the color and alpha channel and save that again.

```py
with_new_alpha = np.dstack([color, blurred_alpha])
```

Drag it, it's got actual alpha:

[image: with new alpha]

Comment: That's a smooth approach